# lvh.me:3000 no longer resolving to localhost:3000 for testing subdomains in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, localhost

I followed [Railscast 121](http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains-revised) to set up subdomains for my site, `www.blog.com`, and got everything working in development. I could use lvh.me:3000 to access my application at both the root url `www.blog.com` and at the specific subdomains I set up e.g. `john-doe.blog.com`

After pushing to Heroku, I can no longer connect to the root url at lvh.me:3000. What could be causing this?

Symptoms in development environment:

- I can access `www.blog.com` through localhost:3000.
- I cannot access `www.blog.com` at lvh.me:3000. but CAN still access `john-doe.blog.com`.
- I opened a DIFFERENT application `www.secondapp.com`, and the root path for this also works at localhost:3000 but not at lvh.me:3000. I have not set up any subdomains for secondapp, but tried the url `john-doe.secondapp.com` just in case, and for some reason, this works. Very strange...

I must have inadvertently adjusted some files, but I don't know where/how. It's completely beyond me why a completely different app would work with a subdomain for an unrelated app. Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: Anyone having trouble with this again?

Comment: Any info about this ? Having the same problem here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the current godaddy outage.  Once their DNS is back up, it should resolve correctly.

In the meantime, you can try editing your hosts file.

Comment: Thanks @kayluhb. This weird behavior had me completely confused. Hopefully, this resolves soon!